# Configuring CardPointe Gateway

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

I've never had to connect to CardPointe before. I'm told it's the new FirstData system but the information I received doesn't look anything at all like the FirstData inputs in Civi. Am I missing the obvious or is the existing FirstData gateway not compatible with CardPointe? In my previous role, another team member handled the payment gateways, but this looks like the account information that's been shared with me by my client is not complete and I'm wondering if I need to get more information or if the default gateway for FirstData is not compatible with this new payment product.

Comment: did you ever get this working?